# How to override Display component on my custom theme

Tags: extjs

ExtJS version: 6.2.1.167
Sencha Cmd v6.5.2.15

This is the scss I want to override:

```
/* /my-project/ext/classic/theme-neutral/sass/var/form/field/Display.scss:52 */
.x-form-display-field-default {
    min-height: 32px; // This is the property I want to override
    font: 400 13px/17px 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', helvetica, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

My custom theme is located at:
my-project/packages/local/custom-theme/

I already tried:

my-project/packages/local/custom-theme/sass/var/form/field/Display.scss

and

my-project/packages/local/custom-theme/classic/sass/var/form/field/Display.scss

But still the ExtJS is loading value from theme-neutral.

I'm reloading with `sencha app refresh classic`.